# Como agrupar Filas en tabla con DataTable

Tags: ajax, datatables

Estoy tratando de agrupar las filas de una tabla generada con DataTables y Ajax, pero no logro que sean agrupadas. Necesito agruparlas por la columna Actividad. La tabla que se genera actualmente es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código JavaScript que estoy utilizando es:

```
function gridView(fechaDesde, fechaHasta) {

    var table = $('#gridView').DataTable({
        "ajax": "/IndicadorServicio/IndicadoresClientesVip/GetIndicadoresClientesVip/?fechaDesde=" + fechaDesde + "&fechaHasta=" + fechaHasta,


        "columns": [
            { "data": "Actividad" },
            { "data": "SlaIndicadores" },
            { "data": "VolumenOk" },
            { "data": "VolumenTotal" },
            { "data": "Cumplimiento" },
            { "data": "Estado" }
        ],
        'rowsGroup': [0],
        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "searchable": false,
                "sortable": false
            }
        ],
        "iDisplayLength": 15,
        "aLengthMenu": [
            [15, 20, 25, 30, -1],
            [15, 20, 25, 30, "All"]
        ],

    });

    return table;
}
```

Estoy utilizando **'rowsGroup': [0]** pero no he tenido éxito.

Comment: ¿Consultaste la [documentación](https://datatables.net/extensions/rowgroup/)? no estoy seguro si así se arma la propiedad `rowsGroup`.

Comment: Si, consulte algunos ejemplos y lo utilizaban de esa forma. No sé si tenga que ver que la tabla se genere  de forma dinámica, probé de varias maneras sin éxito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El código estaba bien solo faltaba el pequeño detalle de agregar la libreria:

```
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/ashl1/datatables-rowsgroup/v1.0.0/dataTables.rowsGroup.js"></script>
```

Ahora funciona perfecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: +1 y que bueno que encontraste la solución, recuerda aceptar tu propia respuesta. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias @MauricioAriasOlave puedo aceptar la respuesta pero mañana. saludos

Comment: Sabes si se puede exportat las filas agrupadas  ?